# Hadoop MapReduce streaming - Best methods to ensure I have processed all log files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

I'm developing Hadoop MapReduce streaming jobs written in Perl to process a large set of logs in Hadoop. New files are continually added to the data directory and there are 65,000 files in the directory.

Currently I'm using `ls` on the directory and keeping track of what files I have processed but even the `ls` takes a long time. I need to process the files in as close to real time as possible.

Using `ls` to keep track seems less than optimal. Are there any tools or methods for keeping track of what logs have not been processed in a large directory like this?

Comment: can you please explain the question in a more elaborate way? with some formatting to understand. If the question is already answered then please post the solution.

Comment: In the end I had to work with the team responsible for processing the logs into Hadoop. They have created a simple database to track the incoming logs which can then be used to determine which logs have not been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the log files once processed by your program.

```
For example:
    command: hadoop fs -mv numbers.map/part-00000 numbers.map/data
```

Once renamed, you can easily identify you processed ones and yet to be processed ones.

Thought this would fix your issue.

Comment: Good idea but I'm not the owner of the files and other teams rely on the naming convention so it's not really an option in this case.